# trouble merging two pandas dataframes by the transposed headers

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary

I'm having trouble merging two of my pandas dataframes together. I have two dictionaries that I turn into dataframes and transpose, and I want to merge the two dataframes based on the first row headers.

I have two dictionaries

```
dict1 = defaultdict(list,
            {'a': [1.9,2.0,2.0],
             'b': [3.9,3.6,2.4]}

dict2 = defaultdict(list,
            {'a': '3.3',
             'a': '3.6'})
```

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame(dict2).transpose()
```

gives

```
     0
a   3.3
b   3.6
```

Then the second datframe I made like:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(dict2)
#add in some other data
df.loc['mean'] = df.mean()
df.loc['SEM'] = df.sem()
df = df.transpose()
df.columns = ['t1', 't2', 't3', 'mean', 'sem']
```

And that gives something like:

```
    t1      t2      t3      mean    sem
a   1.9     2.0     2.0     2.0     0.02
b   3.9     3.6     2.4     3.3     0.34
```

I want to add the things in the other dictionar/dataframe so that I get something like:

```
    t1    t2     t3      mean    sem     NEW_COLUMN
a   1.9   2.0    2.0     2.0     0.02    3.3
b   3.9   3.6    2.4     3.3     0.34    3.6
```

Answer (score 2):

You can simply set a new column of `df` like this;

```py
df['NEW_COLUMN'] = pd.DataFrame(dict2).transpose()
```

Fixing a couple of typos in your OP, the below would be the working code;

```py
dict1 = defaultdict(list,
            {'a': [1.9,2.0,2.0],
             'b': [3.9,3.6,2.4]})

dict2 = defaultdict(list,
            {'a': [3.3],
             'b': [3.6]})

df = pd.DataFrame(dict1)
#add in some other data
df.loc['mean'] = df.mean()
df.loc['SEM'] = df.sem()
df = df.transpose()
df.columns = ['t1', 't2', 't3', 'mean', 'sem']

df['NEW_COLUMN'] = pd.DataFrame(dict2).transpose()
```

Additionally, I would encourage you to take a search first, prior to uploading your post. There is a huge body of Q&As like yours.

Comment: This works perfectly too! Thank you so much